# Cannot add redux.NET to basic Xamarin.Forms project via nuget

Tags: c#, nuget, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

New to Xamarin.forms and PCLs, and I'm trying to add https://github.com/GuillaumeSalles/redux.NET via nuget to a Hello world Xamarin.forms project when I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'Redux.NET 1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

What framework do I need to target - and should I try to update the Xamarin.forms starter project to that framework?  Is there a package config file I can look at to see what .net versions the library is depending on?

The only dependency I see in the .nuspec file is on System.Reactive 3.0.0 which I added already.

Here's my packages.config before I try to add redux

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="System.Reactive" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="System.Reactive.Core" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="System.Reactive.Interfaces" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="System.Reactive.Linq" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="System.Reactive.PlatformServices" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.1.114" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux.NET 1.0.1 has one portable class library assembly folder in its NuGet package:

```
portable-net45+netcore45
```

This maps to PCL profile 7.

If you change your project to use that profile then Redux.NET will install into it without any errors.

To work this out I had a look inside the NuGet package, which is basically a .zip file with a different extension, then used [Stephen Cleary's portable library profiles site](http://portablelibraryprofiles.apps.stephencleary.com) to see which profile was an exact match or the closest to that profile.

Comment: When I switched to profile 7 I get errors saying that the Reactive packages and Xamarin.Forms are not compatible now.  Should I just ask the the Redux.NET owner to update his package?

Comment: Both the Reactive and Xamarin.Forms NuGet packages (both latest and the version you are using) install fine for me into a new PCL project that targets profile 7. This was tested with Xamarin Studio 6.1.

Comment: ok, I removed the existing xamarin.forms and reactive packages and re-added, and now it works.